# How to create a web app that will display data in unique urls for the end-user?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, web-mapping, web-service

Can anyone provide insight on how a novice can construct a fairly rudimentary web app? I would like to send out unique URLs that contain my finished maps instead of exporting them into PDFs and sending them by email. I am using ESRI software and making my final maps in ArcMap 10.1.

The maps each contain 1 polygon, 4 buffers, and between 1 to 500 vector points. I would like the end user to be able to see the points I've mapped for them, zoom in and out of the map area, and click on points to see more data about them. They should not be able to edit any data or add any additional points to the map. I have no prior experience in creating mapping applications.

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum. Could you please mention which platform/software you are going to use? (Like ESRI or Open source ? )

Comment: Thanks :) I am using ESRI, and added this detail to the original question.

Comment: Do you have ArcGIS Server? How proficient are you with programming?

Comment: I currently only have basic skills in programming, but am in the process of taking several classes for this subject specifically.

Answer (score 3):

Go and sign-up with MangoMap (www.mangomap.com), no programming required and it's free. You will be able to put a good looking fully functional map together is a very short time.